# Dynamically mixing in traits to produce decorator composition of finite size

Tags: scala, dynamic, decorator, mixins, traits

I have a finite set of traits, say `Trait1` to `TraitN`, and I want to build a "composite" decorator of `o` that mixes in a *subset* of decorations (for each trait that o mixed in) *at runtime*. Example for N=2:

```
class CommonImpl extends Trait1 ... with TraitN { ... }
trait Trait1Decoration extends Trait1 { ... }  // override some methods
trait Trait2Decoration extends Trait2 { ... }  // override some methods
val oDecorated = o match {
  case t12: Trait1 with Trait2 => new CommonImpl with Trait1Decoration with Trait2Decoration
  case t1: Trait1 => new CommonImpl with Trait1Decoration
  case t2: Trait2 => new CommonImpl with Trait2Decoration
  case _ => new CommonImpl  // no decorations, could also return "o"
} // now, oDecorated has some subset of Traits decorated
```

1. How to achieve this *elegantly*, without 2^N cases and typing each subset of the mixed in traits?
2. How to do it *efficiently* (minimizing the use of reflection & avoiding deep inheritance).
3. Is it possible to do better if we know that no two traits have conflicting methods/fields?

Comment: What use could you have for a thing whose type is unknown at compile time when none of the methods or fields overlap? I mean, there's no way you could ever call any of the methods on it. It might be possible to solve your problem with Dynamic or shapeless - what are you actually trying to do?

Comment: If the methods do not overlap, why not just always use CommonImpl with all the traits?

Comment: @Imm: You could assume that CommonImpl does mix in all the traits. But even if this was not the case, you could still have checks like `oDecorated.isInstanceOf[TraitK]` (imagine traits also serve as tags).

Comment: @Dima: Because you want to decorate only some of them. A contrived example: imagine you have a customizable but monolithic GUI component in which each piece of functionality is achieved via a separate trait. Now, you want to both *add new* and *change some existing* functionality. I hope this sheds some light, even though in this example there might be a better way to do it (but let's assume there is no other way).

Comment: Why don't you give the real example? Perhaps, there is a better way there too? :)